# Selected state of text in a segmented control in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I am working on my first application using Swift and Xcode.

In one of my views, I have a segmented control which has emoticons as the text being displayed. However, I have a problem where whenever one of the emoticons is selected, it becomes blacked out as shown in the image below:

[image: segmentedControl]

I think the problem has to do with the text attributes of the selected state of my segmented control, and my attempt at a fix was setting the text attributes of the selected state to be the same as the text attributes of the normal state:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    moodSelector.setTitleTextAttributes(moodSelector.titleTextAttributesForState(.Normal), forState: .Selected)
}
```

However, this does not seem to work. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor` (formerly known as `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`) to any color and it prevents that behavior. For example, in Swift 3 or 4:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()         // whether `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`, make sure to call the appropriate `super` method, too

    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    moodSelector.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .selected)
}
```

Yielding:

[image: segmented control with emojis]